# How to get rows with the greatest value in one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this query in Postgres:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.nome, P.cognome, F.nomeFacolta, F.id, D.orelez
FROM Persona P, Docenza D, InsErogato IE, Facolta F
WHERE D.id_inserogato = IE.id
    AND IE.id_facolta = F.id
    AND D.id_persona = P.id
    AND D.orelez = ANY ( SELECT MAX(D2.orelez)
        FROM Facolta F2, Docenza D2, Inserogato IE2
        WHERE D2.id_inserogato = IE2.id
            AND IE2.id_facolta = F2.id
            AND IE2.annoaccademico = '2009/2010'
        GROUP BY F2.id)
ORDER BY D.orelez DESC;
```

With this result:

```
nome            | cognome       | NomeFacolta    | id | orelez |

Francesco         Bortolan        Medicina         7    128000  <---
Giampaolo         Dalle Vedove    Economia         2    98000   <---
Mauro             Spera           Scienze          1    87000   <---
Alessandra        Salomoni        Economia         2    80000
Alessandro        Natucci         Economia         2    80000
Attilio           Boner           Medicina         7    80000
Mario Rosario     Buffelli        Lettere          8    76000   <---
Carlo             Capelli         Lettere          8    72000
etc ...
```

I want to change or integrate my query to take only the MAX `orelez` value for `id` (I indicated with an arrow the tuples that I want to keep in the result). Also I want my query takes only the first three attributes, discarding the last two.

This is the desired output for above example:

```
nome            | cognome       | NomeFacolta    

Francesco         Bortolan        Medicina    
Giampaolo         Dalle Vedove    Economia    
Mauro             Spera           Scienze      
Mario Rosario     Buffelli        Lettere     
etc ...
```

How can I change or integrate my query to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you *have* is most probably incorrect. The predicate:

```
WHERE  D.orelez = ANY (SELECT MAX(D2.orelez) ...
```

would include any row that happens to have the same `orelez` as the maximum for any `id`, not just the same `id`.

You *could* repair with:

```
 WHERE (F.id, D.orelez) = ANY (SELECT F2.id, MAX(D2.orelez) ...
```

But there is more. Only the subquery is restricted to `IE2.annoaccademico = '2009/2010'`. The outer query does not have the same restriction, so it will return rows with *any* `annoaccademico`, as long as `orelez` is matched. You would have to repeat the predicate. It's *possible* you really want to find:

*All rows that match the maximum of `orelez` for any `id` with `annoaccademico = '2009/2010'`*.

But that seems rather unlikely. Assuming you really want to find:

***One single row per `id` with the maximum `orelez` and `annoaccademico = '2009/2010'`***

This can be radically simplified with `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (F.id)
       P.nome, P.cognome, F.nomeFacolta
FROM   Persona    P
JOIN   Docenza    D  ON D.id_persona = P.id
JOIN   InsErogato IE ON IE.id = D.id_inserogato
JOIN   Facolta    F  ON F.id = IE.id_facolta
WHERE  IE.annoaccademico = '2009/2010'
ORDER  BY F.id, D.orelez DESC;
```

Detailed explanation and instructions for possible corner cases with NULL values and how to break ties:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

#### Debug instructions

Typical reasons why that might not produce expected results:

1. There are more rows with the same max. value in `D.orelez`. (Do you want to return all of them? Then you need a different query.)
2. The max. value in `D.orelez` is not for `annoaccademico = '2009/2010'`.
3. Row may be eliminated by the joins, not finding a match in `IE` or `F`.
4. There are NULL values in `D.orelez` - add `NULLS LAST` like instructed in the linked answer.

Comment: thanks, it show me 8 row, but non with the max for each id. i would the teacher with MAX "orelez" for each id. in your query there is only a descending order, but not a max selection for id. i'm working on my university database and i can check, for example, that the teacher with max orelez for id 7 is Francesco Bortolan with 128000 "orelez" value. i test your query and for the same id it result another name (Domenico De Leo), and if i put ASC the name change (in Giorgio Talamini).

Comment: This is a further proof that the result is incorrect even though it is very close to the solution. the only thing we must do, i think, is to add the  MAX operator somewhere in your query to make it work , but i do not know where. do you understand on what i want to see in that query?

Comment: @JamesTheBeard: We do not need `max()`. The `ORDER BY` clause takes care of that. This query technique is proven good. Possible explanations why teacher 'Francesco Bortolan' is not in the result: **1.** There is another teacher with the same value *128000* for `orelez` - do you want to return both in this case? **2.** The value *128000* is not for `annoaccademico = '2009/2010'`. **3.** The row is eliminated by the joins because there is no related row in `IE` or `F`. **4.** There are NULL values in `D.orelez` - add `NULLS LAST` like instructed in the linked answer.

Comment: ok we don't need max, i understand. but 1. i have checked and i have seen that there is only one teacher ('Francesco Bortolan') wiith 128000 orelez for the id 7. 2. it can be possible. 3. i rule out this possibility. 4. yes, there are NULL values in D.orelez. i try to do that. I will  let you know if there will be changes in the result or not.

Comment: i just tried and it works with NULLS LAST, you are a genius, thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as you do not want to show `id` and `orelez`, use a subquery that group it by id, and then show the desired columns.

```
SELECT R.nome, R.cognome, R.nomeFacolta
FROM (SELECT 
          F.id, P.nome, P.cognome, F.nomeFacolta, MAX(orelez) as orelez
      FROM 
          Persona P, 
          JOIN Docenza D ON D.id_persona = P.id, 
          JOIN InsErogato IE ON D.id_inserogato = IE.id, 
          JOIN Facolta F ON IE.id_facolta = F.id
      WHERE
          IE2.annoaccademico = '2009/2010'
      GROUP BY 
          F.id, P.nome, P.cognome, F.nomeFacolta) R
ORDER BY 
    R.orelez DESC;
```